# Using awk to trim away parts of a text file outside 2 patterns

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I'd like an elegant `awk` solution to edit the lines in a file. So far I've only managed to complete the task using 2 `sed` commands and 1 `awk` command.

Each file is composed of a header of indeterminate length, followed by the data I want to capture, then a footer which always starts with the same string (WATER). The data is made up of several 3 line chunks, which I'd like to concatenate into single lines, each 3 line chunk starts with the same string (GROUPS).

Whenever I find GROUPS concatenate following lines until the next occurence of GROUPS and repeat, until finding WATER, delete the WATER line, and all following lines to the end of the file.

input:

```
header stuff
more header stuff
even more header stuff
GROUPS data data data data
mo data mo data mo data
even more even more
GROUPS data data data data
mo data mo data mo data
even more even more
GROUPS data data data data
mo data mo data mo data
even more even more
.......
last line of data
WATER footer stuff footer stuff
footer stuff
more footer stuff
even more footer stuff
```

output:

```
GROUPS data data data data mo data mo data mo data even more even more
GROUPS data data data data mo data mo data mo data even more even more
GROUPS data data data data mo data mo data mo data even more even more
........
GROUPS data data data data mo data mo data even more last line of data
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT:

Here are my (probably flaky) solutions!

1:Trim header

```
sed -n '/"GROUPS"/,$p' originalfile > outputfile1
```

2:Trim footer

```
sed '/"WATER"/,$d' outputfile1 > outputfile2
```

3:Concatenate lines

```
awk 'NF&&$1=RS$1' RS="GROUPS" outputfile2 > finaloutputfile
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an  `gnu awk` (gnu due to multiple characters in Record Separator)

```
awk -v RS="GROUPS|WATER" -F"\n" 'p=="WATER"{exit} {$1=p $1}NR>1; {p=RT}' file
GROUPS data data data data mo data mo data mo data even more even more
GROUPS data data data data mo data mo data mo data even more even more
GROUPS data data data data mo data mo data mo data even more even more ....... last line of data
```

By setting `RS` to `GROUPS` and `WATER` and recreate line `$1=p $1` it makes all in one line.
If line then starts with `WATER`, exit.  This way no more line is printed from `WATER` and down.
`p` is set to previous `RT` (the separator used)

Comment: This looks great, though I've realised that my question is flawed, PATTERN1 and PATTERN2 stand in for two completely different strings. So using the word PATTERN as RS won't work. I'm editing the post now. Sorry!

Answer (score 1):

Let's use the arduous way:

```
awk '/^GROUPS/ {if (string) print string; f=1; string=$0; next}
     /^WATER/ {print string; f=0}
     f {string=string" "$0}' file
```

This starts "recording" the lines in a variable `string` when `GROUPS` is found and stop doing so when `WATER` is found. When seeing `GROUPS`, also print the stored string (if it exists) and clean it for the next iteration.

#### Test

```
$ awk '/^GROUPS/ {if (string) print string; f=1; string=$0; next} /^WATER/ {print string; f=0} f {string=string=stri $0}' a
GROUPS data data data data mo data mo data mo data even more even more
GROUPS data data data data mo data mo data mo data even more even more
GROUPS data data data data mo data mo data mo data even more even more ....... last line of data
```

Comment: OP updated his post, should be easy fix on your solution, just replace the `PATTERN`s.  But you have a error in your test, the  `awk` miss some characters at the end.

Comment: Thanks for this one, would +1 but I don't have enough rep yet!

Comment: Uff what a day. Thanks @Jotne for reporting again! :D

Comment: @Arronical no problem and welcome. You can come back to the post once you are over 15 reputation :)